# R: variable lengths differ error when using lm

Tags: r, lm

I am new to R and I'm working on a project, where we have to do some experiments with generating linear regression models.

Here is my code:

```
# regression coefficients
beta1 = 1
beta2 = 0
beta3 = 5
beta4 = 1
beta5 = 1

# generated data
df <- data.frame(y1 = rnorm(n, mean = 50, sd = 1),
                sprem1 = rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                sprem2 = rnorm(n, mean = 10, sd = 2),
                sprem3 = rnorm(n, mean = 10, sd = 2),
                sprem4 = rnorm(n, mean = 20, sd = 2),
                sprem5 = rnorm(n, mean = 20, sd = 1))
fit.lm <- lm(formula = y1 ~ beta1 * sprem1 + beta2 * sprem2 + beta3 * sprem3 + beta4 * sprem4 + beta5 * sprem5, data = df)
```

But I get an error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y1 ~ beta1 * sprem1 + beta2 * sprem2 + : variable lengths differ (found for 'beta1')
```

Where is the problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's `n`? ????

Comment: Any `n` >1 will result in that error.

Comment: n = 100. But why? Isn't it just a scalar multiplication with vector? How can I over-pass the problem?

Comment: See @meriops very good explanation below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the formula, `*` is interpreted as the interaction between each `beta` and the terms from `df`. This interaction is akin to an element-wise product, but the `beta` are scalar, whereas the `sprem` are vectors... so their length differ. 
It's hard to tell what you want to do, but you're probably looking for something like this:

```
fit.lm <- lm(formula = y1 ~ I(beta1 * sprem1) + I(beta2 * sprem2) + I(beta3 * sprem3) + I(beta4 * sprem4) + I(beta5 * sprem5), data = df)
```